# matplot lib adjacent subplots .. stuck at settings

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

This is my code

```py
    #visualize data n strategy    
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4))    
    plt.plot(datanew['DAL'],label='DAL',alpha=0.5,linewidth=2)   
    plt.plot(datanew['SMA30'],label='SMA30',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)   
    plt.plot(datanew['SMA100'],label='SMA100',alpha=0.75,linewidth=2)   
    plt.scatter(datanew.index,datanew['Buy_Signal_Price'],label='Buy' , marker = '^' , color = 'green', s=80)   
    plt.scatter(datanew.index,datanew['Sell_Signal_Price'],label='Sell' , marker = 'v' , color = 'red', s=80)      
    plt.title('DAL Adj Close Price History Buy & Sell')   
    plt.xlabel('Date' , color = 'white' )   
    plt.ylabel('Adj Price US$' , color = 'white' )
    plt.legend(loc='best', fontsize='small')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90 , color = 'white')   
    plt.yticks( color = 'white')   
    plt.show   

    #plot RSI   
    plt.figure(figsize=(16.2, 3))    
    plt.title('RSI Plot')    
    plt.plot(datanew['RSI'],label='RSI',linewidth=1)    
    plt.axhline(0 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'gray',linewidth=1)    
    plt.axhline(10 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'orange',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(20 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'green',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(30 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'red',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(70 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'red',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(80 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'green',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(90 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'orange',linewidth=1)   
    plt.axhline(100 , linestyle = '--', alpha = 0.75, color = 'gray',linewidth=1)
    plt.show
```

[image]

I am trying to join the plots together as adjacent plots .. I know I need to use subplots but I am getting errors when I implement it:

Answer (score 0):

I think I am not able to understand you question fully and what you are trying to do. Please provide the expected and current results.

What I have gathered from it is that You are instantiating two different `figure` objects. How is this supposed to give you adjacent plots. Each figure will be a different one. To use 2 different side by side plots or one over other,

you can use

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsze=your_figsize) # side by side plots 1 row 2 columns
```

Or  you can do

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsze=your_figsize) # stacked plots 2 rows 1 column
```

Now you can access your plots as `ax[0].first_plot()` and `ax[1].second_plot()` instead of `plt.some_plot()`

So change the `plt` to `ax[0]` in the first plot and change `plt` to `ax[1]` for the RSI (second PLOT).

**NOTE**: Please use this carefully as using the axis object `ax[i]` is different from `plt`. For example to set title, you use `plt.title('my_title')` but when you use axis, you use `ax[i].set_title('my_title')`

**EDIT:** If you want everything inside one chart, you can do the following:

```
ax = plt.subplot(1,1,figsize=your_size), sharex=True,sharey=True) # based on your idea whether you want the x_axis to be shared or the y_axis to be shared
```

Comment: reading on using subplots.. i wanted to o adjancent charts instead of different plots as i need the axis to be the same for both plots

Comment: I think you want to share the x or y axis. You can use `sharex` or `sharey`. Please see the edit.